# Geometric explanation of a methodology in the article about Image Denoising

Tags: image-processing, linear-algebra

In article [Ghimpeteanu G., et al. - A Decomposition Framework for Image Denoising Algorithms](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7321034), I found as below:

> *Let $\displaystyle I : \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a gray-level image, and $(x, y)$ be the standard coordinate system of $\mathbb{R}^2$.We denote by $Ix
>  \hspace{.2cm}resp.Iy$ the derivative of $I$ with respect to $x
>  \hspace{.2cm}resp. y$, and by $\nabla I$ the gradient of $I$ . Our
>   image decomposition model for $I$ is a two-stages approach: first, we
>   construct an orthonormal moving frame $(Z_1, Z_2, N)$ of $(\mathbb{R}^3,\|
> \|_2)$ over $\Omega$ that encodes the local geometry of $I$ . Then, we
>   compute the components $(J^1, J^2, J^3)$ of the $\mathbb{R}^3-$valued function
>   $(0, 0, I )$ in that moving frame. More precisely, we consider a
>   scaled version $\mu I$ of $I$ , for $\mu \in ]0, 1]$, and its graph,
>   which is the surface $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ parametrized by $\psi : (x, y)
> \mapsto (x, y,μ I (x, y))$*

**See snapshot-**

[image: demo]

Please someone explain (possibly visualize **geometrically**) 4th and 5th line of the excerpt. i.e

> Our image decomposition model for $I$ is a two-stages approach: first, we construct an orthonormal moving frame $(Z_1, Z_2, N)$ of $(\mathbb{R}^3,\| \|_2)$ over $\Omega$ that encodes the local geometry of $I$ . Then, we compute the components $(J^1, J^2, J^3)$ of the $\mathbb{R}^3-$valued function $(0, 0, I )$ in that moving frame.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! Please use MathJax/ Latex. It will make your question much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation below the section you quote seems to be clear to me:

[image: Screenshot from paper]

It's forming a vector field made up of the largest gradient direction, smallest gradient direction, and the normal to them both.

Comment: Yeah! could you give a intuitive geometric example please..